# How to make executable jar file with eclipse

Tags: java, jar, terminal, command

I Recently finished some simple java program, and I wanted to know about some things that I've just learned and I actually didnt get them at all,

- What is a Java Jar file ?
- How to make one and execute it ? (specific steps if possible)
- What is this manifest file ?
- What is the java command window, terminal window... something that we insert command lines in ?
- How Do we Open it and use it?
  I've come across alot of tutorials and things in books about the jar files, and things about entering these commands(bunch of code) in the java command window to create and make the jar file executable,
  I really appreciate any kind of help, Thanx guys in advance

Comment: take each bullet point, and paste that info google. Crazy, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could easily get your answers by just searching in Internet, particularly in Oracle site:

> The Java™ Archive (JAR) file format enables you to bundle multiple
>   files into a single archive file. Typically a JAR file contains the
>   class files and auxiliary resources associated with applets and
>   applications.
>
> The JAR file format provides many benefits:
>
> Security: You can digitally sign the contents of a JAR file. Users who recognize your signature can then optionally grant your software
>   security privileges it wouldn't otherwise have.
>    Decreased download time: If your applet is bundled in a JAR file, the applet's class files and associated resources can be downloaded to
>   a browser in a single HTTP transaction without the need for opening a
>   new connection for each file.
>   Compression: The JAR format allows you to compress your files for efficient storage.
>   Packaging for extensions: The extensions framework provides a means by which you can add functionality to the Java core platform,
>   and the JAR file format defines the packaging for extensions. By using
>   the JAR file format, you can turn your software into extensions as
>   well.
>       Package Sealing: Packages stored in JAR files can be optionally sealed so that the package can enforce version consistency. Sealing a
>   package within a JAR file means that all classes defined in that
>   package must be found in the same JAR file.
>       Package Versioning: A JAR file can hold data about the files it contains, such as vendor and version information.
>       Portability: The mechanism for handling JAR files is a standard part of the Java platform's core API.

All about Jar Files: **http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/**

> Common JAR file operations Operation  Command To create a JAR file
>     jar cf jar-file input-file(s) To view the contents of a JAR file    jar
>   tf jar-file To extract the contents of a JAR file     jar xf jar-file To
>   extract specific files from a JAR file    jar xf jar-file
>   archived-file(s) To run an application packaged as a JAR file
>   (requires the Main-class manifest header)     java -jar app.jar To invoke
>   an applet packaged as a JAR file

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html